# How does the search view even get rendered?

Tags: java, android

I have been digging around in the search view source code for quite sometime now trying to understand how exactly does the search view even have a user interface to be rendered. First of all here is the source code:

[SearchView source code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/SearchView.java)

So what I don't understand is how does the user interface element of the search view even get rendered when the search view doesn't even have any `onDraw()` method. All that I can see is responsible for the display element is a bunch of view at the start which are in the constructor, the `SearchView` gets a reference to and change the background and set the image of these view. If all that I can see was done is getting references to some views and changing the background as well as the image without having it within the proper view hierarchy then how exactly does it even get rendered?

I understand what you are probably wondering why do I even need to understand this. Well I want to understand this so I can create my own custom search view. Since I only need like 2 function on my search view I figure it would be a lot better to make one that suits my need instead of the thousand of lines of code in the source one. Plus, I want to create one that I know I will understand how to use not the complex default one.

Comment: It's just a `LinearLayout` that gets its child `View`s by inflating a layout into itself. Look at the `inflater.inflate()` call in the constructor. The super classes - `LinearLayout` and `View` - take care of laying things out and drawing.

Comment: it has the draw method, but it's only the one it inherited, it's not overriden

Comment: Hey thanks. I didn't know that inflater.inflate() can inflate the child view into itself. Does that only happen when there is a true parameter or does it  happens when the inflate method is called in the constructor?

Comment: The third argument in the `inflate()` call indicates whether the inflated `View` should be attached to the `ViewGroup` passed as the second. This is the case everywhere, not just in a constructor.

Comment: Hey Thanks can anyone put their answer on the description so I can check it off or do I have to delete this post?